# Blinking/reloading of android resource when using Glide error() and subsequent calls fail

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to specify some Android resource to be displayed when Glide fails to load target image from the internet, so I use the `error()` method. My problem is: when subsequent `load()`s of the internet images fail, resource file is being displayed all the time, but with the visible blink (like a reloading look) after each call to `load()`. I don't want this blinking to be visible.

My code is simple:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .error(resourceId)
        .into(view)
```

What happens:

```
1. Trying to load url1 -> fail -> resource with resourceId is displayed
2. Trying to load url2 -> fail -> blink -> resource with resourceId is displayed
3. Trying to load url3 -> fail -> blink -> resource with resourceId is displayed
```

I would like to see still image without blinking in such case.
Interesting thing is when I use `placeholder()` instead of `error()`, for failed loading of these urls, I get the still placeholder image, without blinking:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .placeholder(resourceId)
        .into(view)
```

Another interesting fact that I discovered is that without trying to load urls from the internet, just only trying to display the Android resource (resourceId), there is also no blinking after subsequent calls:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
        .load(resourceId)
        .into(view)
```

So, it looks like the problem (blinking/reloading) is visible only when using `error()` method.

**All of the `resourceId` values in examples above are exactly the same resource.**

EDIT:
Exactly the same is reproducing in that case:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .error(ColorDrawable(Color.RED))
        .into(view)
```

Comment: This also reproduces with images loaded over http (inside error()), not only Android drawable resources.

Comment: The same blinking can be seen when using just `.error(ColorDrawable(Color.RED))`